# OAuth2 (Code Grant) access_token Meaning

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, access-token

Our team is starting to build out a SMART on FHIR (SoF) application. SoF uses OAuth2 access_tokens to represent authorizations.  Our app is using the code grant to get a token (https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/auth-code-grant/).

I'm pretty new to OAuth2 (used to SAML) and have been reading up on the standard.  I think we may be conflating what the access_token is intended to represent.

Is the intent in OAuth2 that the access_token represents the permissions the resource owner (end user) has granted to the client (web application) to perform on their behalf?

Or is the intent to rely that the resource owner (end user) is allowed to preform certain operations?

For example say the auth token request has a scope called 'contacts-update'.  If we get an access_token back with this scope, does that mean the user has allowed the application to attempt to update contacts (on their behalf) or does it mean that the user has the underlying requirements (they are in the update contacts role) to be able to update contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, the OAuth2 access token represents a permission delegation from a resource owner to a client (application), so the client can perform operations on behalf of the resource owner. That's also why there is a consent page - the user agrees on giving the application permissions (scopes) it requested.

Sometimes, people want to use OAuth2 as a central authentication server and a permission configuration for their applications. They want each application to see all permissions the user has configured for it.  Then it doesn't make sense for application to ask for specific scopes, but to configure the OAuth2 server to return all relevant for that application (identified by a client_id). But I don't think this is the intended way of usage and the OAuth2 specification doesn't cover this scenario.

OAuth2 can also be used for authentication only, if it supports OpenID Connect extension. Then applications can ask for ID tokens. ID token proves identity of a user and the permissions are handled in each application separately.

Comment: Thanks, we are conflating the token meaning.  Josh Mandel responded to my google groups post here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/smart-on-fhir/IzONJwusKvQ and confirmed what you said.  Thanks!